# Powershell関数の引数に、"+"で2つの文字列を連結したものを渡そうとしても、先頭の文字列しか渡せない

Tags: powershell

標題の通りです。
Powershellで以下のようなコードを組みました。
仮にソース名を`concatenate_args.ps1`とします。

```
function func1 {
    Param(
        $param1
    )

    Write-Host "param1 is '$param1'"
}
```

このソースを`. .\concatenate_args.ps1`を実行して読み込み、
`func1 -param1 "hoge" + "fuga"`というコマンドを実行しましたが、
期待した動作になりませんでした。
期待動作：`param1 is hogefuga`
実際の動作：`param1 is hoge`

なぜこのような動作になるのか、
Google検索してもあまり有用な情報にたどり着けておりません。
ご存じの方、どうかご教示をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にパラメータ引数をスペース区切りで渡すと別々の引数として受け取る前提に即して動作しています。

```
> function func1 {
>>    Param(
>>        $param1
>>    )
>>    Write-Host "param1 is '$param1'" 
>>    $Args  # この行を追加
>> }
> func1 "hoge" + "fuga" 
param1 is 'hoge'
+
fuga
```

下記の例は上記と同様の結果ですが、少し視点が変わって分かりやすくなるでしょうか。

```
> echo + - * "hoge" "fuga" 
+
-
*
hoge
fuga
```

期待した動作にする方法はいくつもあります。

```
# $()で変数としてまとめる
func1 $("hoge" + "fuga")

# 上記と同様
func1 $(-join("hoge", "fuga"))
# 先に結合しておく
$s = "hoge" + "fuga" 
func1 $s

# "ダブルクォーテーション文字列"の変数展開(sub-expression expansion)
$s1 = 'hoge'
func1 "${s1}fuga" 

# 'シングルクォーテーション文字列'を無理やり拡張(ExecutionContext の ExpandString)
$s2 = 'fuga'
func1 $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('${s1}${s2}')
```

**参考資料**

[How do I concatenate strings and variables in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113413)
[ExecutionContext の ExpandString](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2#executioncontext-expandstring)
[Windows PowerShell Language Specification Version 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389)をダウンロードした資料の"2.3.5.2 String literals"

Comment: 言われてみれば確かに、スペースで区切ると引数と取られてしまいますね。+ を使うかどうかは関係ありませんね。大前提が抜けておりました。ご指摘ありがとうございました！

Comment: もしこの回答で質問が解決いたしましたら、[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。(承認後により良い回答が出た場合は、承認マークを別回答に付け替えることも可能です)